# Data not populating on excel file C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a form that allows user to select item from a list on a grid and allows them to export the data corresponding to the selected items. The data should be exported to the existing excel template. I tried some codes but what happens is when the downloaded excel file is opened it just shows blank. Can you please help me why it happens and what's wrong with my code.

Below is my code: Thanks in advance

```
try
        {

            UpdateDataSelection();

            string pFileName = "SubconOneLineList_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".xls";

            string pSubConCodeLists = string.Empty;
            string pJobCodeKey = string.Empty;

            string pCountryCode = string.Empty;
            string pWorkCategoryCode = string.Empty;
            string pCapacityCode = string.Empty;
            string pOperativeCountryCode = string.Empty;

            string pNameAbbr = string.Empty;
            string pAffiliates = string.Empty;

            pSubConCodeLists = string.Join(",", DataSelection);
            if (pSubConCodeLists == string.Empty)
            {
                GetSubconDatabaseFilter(out pSubConCodeLists, out pNameAbbr, out pJobCodeKey, out pCountryCode, out pOperativeCountryCode, out pWorkCategoryCode, out pAffiliates, out pCapacityCode);
            }

            string pGridFilter = (rgvSubcontractor.MasterTableView.FilterExpression == null ? string.Empty : rgvSubcontractor.MasterTableView.FilterExpression);
            string pSortString = "";
            if (rgvSubcontractor.MasterTableView.SortExpressions != null)
            {
                pSortString = ((rgvSubcontractor.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.GetSortString() == null) || (rgvSubcontractor.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.GetSortString() == string.Empty) ? pSortString : rgvSubcontractor.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.GetSortString());
            }
            pSortString = (pSortString == string.Empty ? "COMPANY_NAME ASC" : pSortString + ", COMPANY_NAME ASC");

            DataTable pDTSubconOneLineList = mSubContractorBS.getRptSubContractorOneLineList(pSubConCodeLists, pNameAbbr, string.Empty, string.Empty, pJobCodeKey, pCountryCode, pOperativeCountryCode, pWorkCategoryCode, pAffiliates, pCapacityCode);
            DataView pDVSubconOneLineList = new DataView(pDTSubconOneLineList);
            if (pGridFilter != string.Empty)
            {
                pDVSubconOneLineList.RowFilter = pGridFilter;
            }
            pDVSubconOneLineList.Sort = pSortString;
            pDTSubconOneLineList = pDVSubconOneLineList.ToTable();

            pDTSubconOneLineList.TableName = "USP_RPT_SUBCON_ONE_LINE_LIST";


            Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();


            string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\SIS\\Template\\Download\\Subcon_Profile_List_Import_Template.xlsx";
            //string targetPath = Convert.ToString(Session["App_Data_Path"]) + "EXPORT_OUTPUT";
            string targetPath = Convert.ToString(Server.MapPath("~")) + "EXPORT_OUTPUT";
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, pFileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            File.Copy(path, destFile, true);

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "AN" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count.ToString()).Clear();

            object[,] objData = null;

            int rowcount = pDTSubconOneLineList.Rows.Count;

            objData = new Object[pDTSubconOneLineList.Rows.Count, pDTSubconOneLineList.Columns.Count];

            for (int row = 0; row < pDTSubconOneLineList.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for(int column= 0; column < pDTSubconOneLineList.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    objData[row, column] = pDTSubconOneLineList.Rows[row][column].ToString();
                }
            }

            ((Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1]).Select(Type.Missing);

            xlWorkBook.Save();
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            xlWorkSheet = null;
            xlWorkBook = null;
            xlApp = null;
            GC.Collect();

            string pMimeType = string.Empty;
            string pEncoding = string.Empty;
            string pExtension = string.Empty;

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", hdDownLoadToken.Value));
            Response.ContentType = pMimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pFileName);
            Response.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHelper.HandleError(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Quick question. Have you checked that your data table contains rows and columns. What is the row and column count?

Comment: Don't take this approach to write Excel files.  Creating instances of the Excel application will cause memory leaks over time, and Office applications don't belong on a web server.  There are other tools (libraries), even free ones, that can write excel.  If it's just raw data, write in CSV format, but save with extension XLS.  It'll work!

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually writing the data to the Sheet.

After your for loop filling objData, try:

```
Excel.Range targetRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "AN" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count.ToString());
targetRange.Value = objData;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried the code you provided and what happens now is when the excel file is downloaded it says corrupted but still can open and when I opened it, it contains the layout of the form. And when I opened the file copy it shows the data but repeating up to the last cell. I dont know what happened.

Comment: Can you check in debug mode that pDTSubconOneLineList does not contain repeated values, prior to setting objData?  The write to Excel looks ok.  I suspect you may have a problem with your data selection.

Comment: the previous code made for the exporting of data is through RDLC which is done by a different programmer.  'ReportDataSource pRds = new ReportDataSource("USP_RPT_SUBCON_ONE_LINE_LIST", pDTSubconOneLineList); '  this is the datasource. then in the current i just got the datatable and i think this is why it's repeating when exported. how to include the sp which is same as the old code?